# Hibernate with MongoDB

Tags: spring, hibernate, mongodb, hibernate-ogm

I'm looking for resources showing how to integrate MongoDB with Hibernate (preferably from within spring) so that I can switch between a RDBMS and a NoSql alternative: does anyone have experience doing this?

Comment: please have a look at Hibernate OGM. Its still young but they have some interesting stuff coming up.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can't easily do this. The point of Hibernate is to map Java Objects to a relational database. Although Hibernate abstracts a lot of details away you still need to understand how relational databases work with things such as foreign and primary keys, and the performance implications of queries you run. MongoDB requires an entire different way of designing your database focusing on objects instead of columns and tables. while you may be able to create a Hibernate dialect for MongoDB creating a design that would work on both a relational database and a NoSql database will give you a design that works poorly on both.

Comment: please have a look at Hibernate OGM. Its still young but they have some interesting stuff coming up.

Answer (score 34):

What about [Hibernate OGM](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/ogm.html)? It provides JPA for *No-SQL* databases.

Comment: Specifically, MongoDB is one of the dialects by Hibernate OGM out of the box. Check out the [reference guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#ogm-mongodb) to learn more.

Answer (score 24):

Migration would be easier if you use Spring MongoTemplate (similar to HibernateTemplate). 
Among its features is support for JPA annotations (although, I'm not sure to what extent).
See more: http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb

You'll need the following:

1. Add spring-data-mongodb JAR to your project (available in maven
   central).
2. Add mongo-java-driver JAR to your project (available in
   maven central).
3. Use the provided MongoTemplate class in a similar
   manner to HibernateTemplate. E.g.:
   `mongoTemplate.findById(id, MyClass.class);`
   `mongoTemplate.insert(myObject);`

Here's a concrete example with code: [use-spring-and-hibernate-with-mongodb](http://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/use-spring-and-hibernate-with-mongodb/)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Java then you can use **Hibernate OGM** it provides Java Persistence support for **NoSQL** databases.

For more details visit http://hibernate.org/ogm/

Answer (score 4):

There is nice work done earlier as:

- http://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/use-spring-and-hibernate-with-mongodb/
- http://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/unit-test-your-springhibernate-and-mongodb-setup/#comments

refer to these links. it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [kundera](http://code.google.com/p/kundera/), which uses JPA-annotations to read/write your object from/to a mongodb. If you ara familiar with hibernate, it should be quite straightformard to use.

I recently tried [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/), which takes the same approach, but with its own annotations.
It works fine

Answer (score 1):

May this blog helps: http://drorbr.blogspot.com/2010/02/migrating-springhibernate-application.html 
Here Dror Bereznitsky describes nicely how to integrate a sping/hibernate based solution with mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, [PlayORM](http://buffalosw.com/products/playorm/) also supports MongoDB now. PlayORM is an object NoSQL mapping solution so you can write POJO’s and let it deal with all the details of marshalling/unmarshalling to MongoDB. Visit its [documentation](http://buffalosw.com/wiki/playorm-documentation/) here

Answer (score 1):

I think Hibernate provides desired functionality. Take a look at this, found on their official website:
Mixing several NoSQL datastores in one application, e.g. use Neo4j for your friendship graph and MongoDB for your blog posts. Or mix NoSQL and relational databases.

[reference](http://hibernate.org/ogm/)

Answer (score 0):

Well just to give you an example, I am doing somehting simmilar. In ColdFusion, Hibernate is integrated and in order to save your Hibernate Object, you hvae to do EntitySave(Obj). However what we have done is build the Orm object, and then use a mongoDB Coldfusion component and just save the object by going mongo.Save(obj,collectionName).